# Haskell, hGetContents blocking problem (reading more lines)

Tags: haskell

I am writing a TCP client-server and I want to pass more lines from server to client.

Server:

```
      hPutStrLn handle message
```

Client:

```
    do
      response <- hGetContents handle 
      putStrLn response
      putStrLn "done!"
```

However, I get the message but client blocks after printing it, and string "done!" is not printed.
What would be a proper way to read more lines in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `hGetContents` does.  It returns a lazy list of all the values it has read so far *and will read in the future*.  The string doesn't finish until hitting the end of the input - which in the case of a TCP connection would mean the socket was closed.

Do you want `hGetLine` instead?

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to get all the lines of the message, not just the first.